# Is data transfer from a Pixel 3a XL possible via USB 3?

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode, data-transfer, usb-c, google-pixel-3a-xl

The Google Pixel 3a XL has a USB C port.

Is it possible to connect it to a computer that only has a USB 3 port to transfer data between the computer and the Pixel 3a XL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [GSM arena](https://www.gsmarena.com/google_pixel_3a-9408.php) the Google Pixel 3a has an USB 2.0 type-C connector.

Note that the USB transfer speed is independent of the used USB connector type.

Therefore USB 3.0 is not supported by the Pixel 3a - you can only use USB 2.0 connections for data transfer.

Comment: Thanks Robert.  Even though USB 3.0 is not supported, it should still be able to transfer data (backwards compatible) via a USB 3.0 port, correct?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Of course you can do this. Every USB 3.0/3.1/3.2 port can be used with USB 2.0 and even USB 1.1 devices.

Comment: Great. That's my understanding as well.